# ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA error on using cosmosDB sdk with java

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb

I'm getting the following exception when using cosmosdb sdk for Java:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_TRAILING_COMMA
    at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.internal.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.rx.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl.<clinit>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:132)
    at com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.rx.AsyncDocumentClient$Builder.build(AsyncDocumentClient.java:224)
    at Program2.<init>(Program2.java:25) 
    at Program2.main(Program2.java:30)
```

I'm just trying to connect to the CosmosDB using AsyncDocumentClient. The exception occurs in that moment.

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100); 
scheduler = Schedulers.from(executorService); 

client = new AsyncDocumentClient.Builder()
          .withServiceEndpoint("[cosmosurl]")
          .withMasterKeyOrResourceToken("[mykey]")
          .withConnectionPolicy(ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault())
          .withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Eventual)
          .build();
```

I heard about some library conflict but I haven't found the properly fix.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a runtime version conflict between the dependency libraries. I am not familiar with azure stuff, so i have no idea which ones are involved here.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my working sample.

Java code:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.ConnectionPolicy;
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.rx.AsyncDocumentClient;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AsyncDocumentClient client = new AsyncDocumentClient.Builder()
                .withServiceEndpoint("https://XXX.documents.azure.com:443/")
                .withMasterKeyOrResourceToken("XXXX")
                .withConnectionPolicy(ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault())
                .withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Eventual)
                .build();
        System.out.println(client);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```